# Why can't I press the ok button in pycharm setting of interpreter

Tags: pycharm, virtual-environment

I installed a Python package and I can't find it in my site packages. Python version 3.11,
Someone said he simply checked the inherit global site-packages check box, in Pycharm settings for interpreters  which I have done but I'm unable to press the okay button it is grayed out ... Please help

[image: I can't press the ok button]

Comment: hint: next time take a screenshot not a picture of the screen (that's `CTRL`+`ALT`+`PRINT SCR` on Windows)

Comment: Okay, noted, so please what can I do?

Comment: Check the folder you selected is not there already. Because if it is, then "New" will not work. In such case rename it/remove and try again